# How can I deploy a Rust binary I compiled on my machine to Heroku without compiling it on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, deployment, rust

Building on Heroku takes too long.

This [blog post](https://preslav.me/2019/04/20/deploying-native-go-binary-on-heroku/) describes how to deploy a Go binary to Heroku by hijacking the buildpack trigger. This still requires checking the binary into a Git repo. However, there is the [heroku-builds addon](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-builds) that seems to be able to package up files as-is.

Answer (score 2):

I usually deploy a statically compiled rust binary using Musl.

```sh
cd myapp
cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
export ARTIFACT_PATH=$PWD/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release
```

and then deploy:

```sh
heroku create myapp --buildpack https://github.com/ph3nx/heroku-binary-buildpack.git
heroku git:clone --app myapp
pushd myapp
mkdir ./bin
cp -v ${ARTIFACT_PATH}/myapp ./bin/
echo 'web: PORT=$PORT bin/myapp' > Procfile
git add -A; git commit -am 'init'
git push heroku master
```

> `git push heroku master` output:

```
Enumerating objects: 8, done.
Counting objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 2.52 MiB | 1.73 MiB/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: https://github.com/ph3nx/heroku-binary-buildpack.git
remote: -----> Null app detected
remote: -----> Nothing to do.
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 2.5M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v3
remote:        https://myapp.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

As you we can see, it's just a few files:

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── compile
│   ├── detect
│   ├── myapp
│   └── release
└── Procfile

1 directory, 5 files
```